# sql - remove char from all names of objects in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to remove `name_` part of each name in database, `name_` is mistakenly inserted into db and now in 30 object names. if i remove manuelly from db, it takes me much time.

one example is: `name_john`. it should be `john`.

how can i delete this `name_` from all names of all objects in db with some sql statement?

Comment: Are you talking about column names or column values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is about column values that you need to modify, you could use the [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function like this:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columnname = REPLACE(columnname, 'name_', '')
WHERE columnname LIKE '%name\_%' ESCAPE '\'
;
```

That would remove all entries of `name_` in `columnname`. If there can be no more than one entry (or if only one needs to be removed) and its position is fixed, you could use the [`INSERT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_insert) function instead, which, despite its name, can also replace and delete substrings. This is how you could use it if the position of `name_` was e.g. at the beginning:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columnname = INSERT(columnname, 1, 5, '')
WHERE columnname LIKE 'name\_%' ESCAPE '\'
;
```

Answer (score 3):

If it are column values you can do it with an update statement.

```
UPDATE table_reference
SET column_reference = SUBSTRING(column_reference, 6)
WHERE column_reference LIKE 'name\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```